# Codeigniter form validation does not show errors

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

Codeigniter form validation does not show errors
Whenever I submit incomplete fields in my given form in codeigniter it does not show any errors and instead redirects me to about:blank page
View:view/forms.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

<?php echo form_open('form'); ?>

<h5>Username</h5>
<input type="text" name="username" value="" size="50" />

<h5>Password</h5>
<input type="password" name="password" value="" size="50" />

<h5>Password Confirm</h5>
<input type="password" name="passconf" value="" size="50" />

<h5>Email Address</h5>
<input type="email" name="email" value="" size="50" />

<div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
<?php
class Form extends CI_Controller {
  function index()
    {
    /*Load the form validation helpers*/
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    /*Load the form validation helpers*/
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
    /*Set the form validation rules*/
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('passconf', 'Password Confirmation', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');
    /*Check if the form passed its validation */
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $this->load->view('forms');
        }
        else {
            $this->load->view('formsuccess');
        }
    }
}
?>
```

currently I am not going for database validation only checking that all the fields are filled in and if yes goto success page or show validation errors on the same page!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `required` in view

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="" size="50" required/>

<h5>Password</h5>
<input type="password" name="password" value="" size="50" required/>

<h5>Password Confirm</h5>
<input type="password" name="passconf" value="" size="50" required/>

<h5>Email Address</h5>
<input type="email" name="email" value="" size="50" required/>
```

controller-

```
function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

         $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

    }

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
```

**Check your .htaccess file too**

Comment: thats front end validation,then what will be the use of codeigniter validation library!
Even then success page is not loaded instead about:blank page is loaded

Comment: i have edited the post,try editing the controller as such,and your `form_open(form)` and your load view is `forms` is both actually different ones?

Comment: no same result :(
thats becaus forms.php is view file and form.php is controller

Comment: What do u mean its only showing the blank page i. E about blank

Comment: think there is problem with my xampp as i transferred the  folder to my other laptop and it works perfectly over there!! Will try reinstalling xampp

Answer (score 0):

think there is problem with my xampp as i transferred the  folder to my other laptop and it works perfectly over there!! Will try reinstalling xampp